# React redux prevent updating component from old state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-saga

I have map component, which map center location is connected to redux state.

```
<YandexMapView
                ref={this._mapRef}
                location={this.props.location}
                onInteraction={(event) => this.onMapPositionChanged(event)}
                geocodingEnabled={true}
                onGeocoding={(event) => this.onGeocoding(event)}
            />
```

My saving function is

```
onMapPositionChanged(event: OnInteractionResult) {
    const {latitude, longitude} = event;
    this.props.dispatch(updateLocation({
        latitude, longitude,
    }));
}
```

When I move map, and after that I move it again in a short time, before my old state will update to component I have infinite jitter effect.

The abnormal sequence is:

1. Component send event to update state with data {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}.
2. State is updated to {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}.
3. At that time component send another event to update state = {latitude: 
   2, longitude: 2} because I moved the map.
4. Component receive old state in props = {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}
5. Component updates its map location to old {latitude: 1, longitude: 1} and send again {latitude: 1, longitude: 1}

and all these actions become infinite...

I tried to add delay or throttle to my redux sagas, but it doesn't help.

Comment: So youre saying that you have created an infinite loop? Maybe its due to double events, any way you can limit those to firing just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate events from map movement initiated by the user from events generated by moving the map programmatically. You likely want to call `onMapPositionChanged` only for events from the *user* moving the map.

You haven't specified which library you are using, but for React Native e.g. doomsower/react-native-yandexmapkit's `onInteraction` callback has a [`type` attribute](https://github.com/doomsower/react-native-yandexmapkit#events) that can be used for this purpose. Whatever library you are using probably supports something similar.